# Time Format - Coldfusion 9

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, timestamp, coldfusion-9

I am trying to create a time stamp in coldfusion that would include milliseconds.

My issue is that I cannot find a code anywhere that would allow me to keep the format consistent by controlling leading zeros.

This is my format:

```
<cfoutput> 
<cfset todayDate = #Now()#> 
<ul> 
    <li>#TimeFormat(todayDate, "HH:mm:ssl")# </li>
</ul> 
</cfoutput>
```

I just need something like "HH:mm:ssll" or some other method that will ensure that I would have a 9 digit timestamp at all times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Milliseconds with leading zeros?

```
<li>
  #TimeFormat(todayDate, "HH:mm:ss")##NumberFormat(TimeFormat(todayDate, "l"),"000")#
</li>
```

FYI, `l` has maximum of 3 digits.  So I'm not sure about your 9-digits limit.

Comment: 9 digits would be HH-MM-SS-ZZZ That's what I meant by 9. I ran the test code I posted as an example and sometimes I was getting results like 10-45-34-56, what I need instead is 10-45-34-056.

Answer (score 8):

Use [java SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)!

```
<cfscript>
   createObject('java','java.text.SimpleDateFormat').init('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z').format(now());
</cfscript>
```

Produces `2010-07-19 11:40:14.051 EST`

```
<cfscript>
   createObject('java','java.text.SimpleDateFormat').init('HH:mm:ss.SSS').format(now());
</cfscript>
```

Produces `09:45:12.009` - with leading zeros

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was asked, does it?

Comment: It will produce a consistent 9 digit timestamp if you use the mask "HH:mm:ss.SSS". I gave a full example mask as an example, so it wouldn't get confused with timeFormat() and its inability to handle the date part.

Comment: Three SSS gives you leading zeros on your milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it when you said:

> I just need something like "HH:mm:ssll"...

Just add a third "l" to have the correct number of placeholders:

```
<cfoutput> 
    <cfset todayDate = #Now()#> 
        <ul> 
            <li>#TimeFormat(todayDate, "HH:mm:sslll")# </li>
        </ul> 
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <cfscript>
    function getUniqueID() {
        rightNow = now();
return (dateformat(rightNow,'yyyymmdd') & timeformat(rightNow,"HHmmss") &NumberFormat(TimeFormat(rightNow, "l"),"000") & RandRange(10000, 99999));

    }
    </cfscript>

<cfdump var="#getUniqueID()#">
```

Just sharing my code in case someone needs to create a unique timestamp for whatever purpose.

Credits to Henry for the `NumberFormat` part of the code

Comment: Except that is _not_ guaranteed to be a unique ID. If you need unique, use `createUuid()`, if you need a timestamp prefix it with `getTickCount()`.

Comment: Why not? I thought going down to milliseconds would be enough to create a unique timestamp.

Comment: Because calling a function doesn't always take more than a millisecond (or indeed prevent other threads calling it at same time), and RandRange provides random numbers, not unique numbers - it's possible (though somewhat unlikely) that RandRange could return the same value twice in a row, and if that coincides with the function being called in the same millisecond, you've got a collision. (Not a _likely_ event, but a possible one.)

Comment: You could solve it with a suitable lock in the function, but a far better solution is simply to use the built-in function designed to provide a guaranteed unique id - i.e. [createUuid](http://cfdocs.org/createuuid)